# How to get IntelliJ to properly recognize correct `Proxy` implementations?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How to get IntelliJ to properly recognize correct `Proxy` implementations?

I get the following four warnings, though I believe the code to be correct. The code clearly works for the methods warned about.

```
Incompatible type might be returned when proxying method 'hashCode()':
 required: exactly Integer; got: exactly Boolean 

Incompatible type might be returned when proxying method 'equals()':
 required: exactly Boolean; got: exactly Integer 

Incompatible type might be returned when proxying method 'equals()':
 required: exactly Boolean; got: exactly String 

Null might be returned when proxying method 'equals()':
 this may cause NullPointerException
```

#### MWE follows

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-231.8109.175, built on March 28, 2023
```

```
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ProxyTest {
    interface Abc { }

    @Test
    public void lookAtProxy() {
        Abc a = (Abc) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Abc.class.getClassLoader(),
            new Class<?>[]{Abc.class},
            (proxy, method, args) -> {

            if (method.equals(Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("equals", Object.class))) {
                // IntelliJ complains here that hashCode should return an Integer
                return (Boolean) (proxy == args[0]);
            } else if (method.equals(Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("hashCode"))) {
                // IntelliJ complains here that equals should return an Boolean
                return (Integer) System.identityHashCode(proxy);
            } else if (method.equals(Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString"))) {
                // IntelliJ complains here that equals should return an Boolean
                return Abc.class.getSimpleName();
            } else {
                // IntelliJ complains here that equals may return null
                return null;
            }
        });

        System.out.println(a.equals(a));
        System.out.println(a.hashCode());
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
872627152
Abc
```

---

I have tried

- casting the returns to `Object`
- permuting of condition orderings
- permuting lhs and rhs of `equals`
- using `Object.class.getDeclaredMethod(...)`
- using `Object.class.getMethod(...)`
- using `Abc.class.getMethod(...)`
- renaming classes (in case IntelliJ doesn't like or requires prefix or suffix)
- caching the method lookups in variables
- implementing the case logic in other methods

Comment: Interesting finding, same happens in 2023.1 Ultimate. If you change *ALL* the code that checks method names to use `getName()`, e.g. `if (method.getName().equals("equals"))`, IntelliJ stops complaining. I believe this is just a limitation in its logic and you can safely ignore the warnings. I have the impression that changing your code to simply use `getName` wouldn't hurt the correctness of your program either (not 100% sure though).

Comment: [Bug reported](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-319193/Proxy-InvocationHandler-Inspection-incorrectly-warns-for-equals-hashCode) to jetbrains

Comment: Bug should be fixed in 2023.1.3